# What to call & how to compute errors in a very asymmetric sample

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Consider the following sample $\{1.25,1.5,1.75,2.0,2.25,2.5,2.75,10.\}$. Mean is $\mu=3.$, standard deviation is $\sigma\approx 2.69$. I am wondering how to compute and what to call error bars in the context of this sample.

Using the standard error ($\mu \pm \sigma$) will obviously not be very useful as it would comprise the complete sample except for one outlier. Using 1st and 4th quartile $[1.75,2.5]$ describes the sample much better but seems odd to use for plotting error bars as well as the mean is not inside this interval.

One could use the mean deviation of all upper (above the mean) and all lower (below the mean) observations, which would give $[2.,10.]$, but there does not seem to be a proper name for this concept (discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27829/upper-lower-standard-error-makes-sense)). I tend to favor this option but have trouble referring to what is plotted in a convenient way (calling it "mean deviation", "standard deviation", "standard errors", or "mean errors" is just plain wrong; calling it "errors" or "upper/lower errors" seems unspecific and also seems to imply some kind of estimation which is not involved; calling it "upper/lower deviation" is unspecific and readers would likely assume it to refer to something like the standard deviation).

How are error bars usually computed for such a sample and what are they then usually referred to (other than "error bars")?

Comment: I believe each error bar in the figure you reference is based on a different sample (and found as explained below the figure). I don't think it is common to use 'error bars' for a single dataset in isolation such as yours. Perhaps you could use your sample to find a confidence interval for the mean of the population from which it was randomly drawn.

Comment: The sample above was just an illustrative example. I have a number of samples with more observations than this one but some of which are just as asymmetric. And I am wondering if it is possible to visualize those with error bars and (assuming that this is possible) how.

Comment: In order to get useful error bars or CIs for highly skewed data, you would probably need to know something about the underlying distribution. In the example you show 10 seems to be an outlier. My Answer below shows how to find asymmetrical CIs for a sample from the highly skewed exponential distribution. If you know nothing about the population distribution, you might want to consider bootstrap CIs. For a different kind of display, you might look into box plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERROR BARS. As far as I can discover, the term 'error bar' can refer to almost
any line that indicates a degree of uncertainty. In different
disciplines and applications they can indicate the standard deviation (SD) of data, the standard error (often SD divided by square root of sample size), or confidence interval (90%, 95%, or 99%). See the very brief Wikipedia 'error bars' article.

ASYMMETRICAL SAMPLES. However, I think your main question has to do with asymmetrical populations, samples from them, and error bars representing 
an estimate of a population parameter. A common asymmetrical
family of distributions in statistics is the gamma family, which
includes highly right-skewed exponential distributions.

As an example of asymmetrical confidence intervals, I will show
that confidence intervals for estimates of the mean of an 
exponential distribution are asymmetrical.

The population mean of an exponential distribution is estimated
by the sample mean of a sample. Suppose the data are $X_1, \dots, X_{10}$ from an exponential distribution with mean $\mu.$ Then
the sample mean $\bar X/\mu$ has a gamma distribution with
shape parameter $n = 10$ and scale parameter $1/n =0.1$ (rate
parameter $n=10$). Let numbers $L$ and $U$ cut probability 2.5% from the lower and upper ends of this distribution. Then
$$P(L < \bar X/\mu < U) = P(\bar X/U < \mu < \bar X/L) = 0.95,$$
so that $(\bar X/U, \bar X/L)$ is a 95% confidence interval for $\mu.$ Specifically for $n = 10$: $L =  0.480$ and $U = 1.708$ (from statistical software).

CI FOR EXPONENTIAL MEAN. As a numerical example, consider the following sorted data (perhaps
lifetimes in weeks of 10 electronic components subjected to
unfavorable operating conditions):

`0.546, 0.742, 1.005, 3.160, 3.594, 4.057, 4.156, 5.483, 12.590, 21.383.`

Here, $\bar X = 5.6716$ and the 95% CI for $\mu$ is
$(3.32, 11.83).$

Notice that the data are strongly right skewed, with several
small values close together at the left end and a 'tail' with
large values scattered out towards the right end. Also,
notice that 5.67 is closer to the left end of the CI than to
the right end. (Typically, a CI will not include ALL of the data, its
purpose is to give an interval of values in which we might
logically expect the population mean to lie.)

*Notes* (1) Error bars often occur in clusters. If we conducted half a dozen experiments of this type on
components of different specifications. We might have made
a data summary of six confidence intervals in a column.
Even though each CI can be considered to have an 'error probability'
of only 5%, the COLLECTION of six CIs taken together 
may be considerably higher. So we would have to be cautious
drawing conclusions about PATTERNS of behavior among the
six kinds of components. (There are ways to make CIs so
that the error rate of the FAMILY of CIs is only 5%, but that is
another topic.)

(2) Suppose we had not noticed the skewness or known that
the data above are from an exponential distribution. Then we might
INCORRECTLY have assumed a symmetrical normal distribution
and used a symmetrical CI based on the t-distribution. That
incorrect symmetrical interval would be of the form $\bar X \pm 2.262 S/\sqrt{10},$ which would compute to $(1.01, 10.34).$ [For the data shown above $S =  6.52,$ a statistic not needed for the correct CI.]